# choosing certain row to update in database

Tags: php, database

I was wondering how I would go about selecting certain rows from a database, I need to do this for each row automatically so it is on it's own, but I cannot do it by ID, is there some way I can get around to select one certain row to update?
Would it be something like this?
this is of course missing the execute() and connection but these parts are where my question lies

```
$actual_quote = (empty($_GET['actual_quote'])) ? : $_GET['actual_quote'] ;

$update1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE data SET dislikes = :dislikes WHERE actual_quote = $actual_quote");
```

and here;s a picture of the database

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5EWo.png

so how would I go about picking one row, I will be doing this in a while loop so I would need it to happen over and over again, so it can't be unique, I am confused, can someone give a suggestion?

Comment: I was not able to understand your question but I can tell you that the query is open to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

SQL's `UPDATE` will set one or more fields to a given value and it will know which rows to update with the new values with the `WHERE` statement.

Your code looks good, though I have one improvement:

```
$actual_quote = (empty($_GET['actual_quote'])) ? : $_GET['actual_quote'] ;

$update1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE data SET dislikes = :dislikes WHERE actual_quote = :quote");
```

And that is not to reference `$actual_quote` in the SQL itself but to use it as a parameter, as you did with `:dislikes`. That way you can prevent some stupid SQL injections. Otherwise, this looks sound.

Just keep in mind that if you have the same `actual_quote` for multiple rows, all rows will be updated with the new value for `dislikes`.

---

Addendum: You should be able to use `LIMIT 1` so that only one row will be updated (`UPDATE ... LIMIT 1`) but the best here would be to use the unique ID (why can't you use it) or ensure that the quote is unique.

`LIMIT 1` isn't a great fix for the "same quote in multiple entries" problem since it doesn't guarantee that the correct entry will be affected; all it guarantees is that only one row will be changed.

**tl;dr:** fix SQL injection, your code should work but consider using the unique ID you have, or make sure the quote row is unique for each entry.